# When I hover the curve on any point,the tooltip will display the first point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I hover the curve on any point,the tooltip will display the first point.And I have tried my best to find out answer to resolve it,but failed.

Below capture is when my mouse is put on the middle of the chart:
[image]

And there is another question: my highcharts is a live chart,when there is new data produced,it will be add to the charts dynamicly.But when added to the chart,it added from the first point,not the last point.Below is my capture:

[image]
Below is charts configure:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/highstock.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exporting.js")'type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="T">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var T_chart;
    var T_options;
    var T1_data = [];
    var T2_data = [];

    T_options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'T',      
        type: 'spline'     
    },
    navigator:{
        enabled:false        
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'day',
            text: 'Day'
        }, {
            count: 1,
            type: 'week',
            text: 'Week'
        }, {
            count: 1,
            type: 'month',
            text: 'Month'
        }, {
            count: 1,
            type: 'year',
            text: 'Year'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 0          
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature Chart'    
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false       
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false     
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            x: -10,        
            y: 0
        }
    },
    series: []
};

function draw_chart() {
    storenum = $(".StoreNum").val();     
    $.getJSON("HisGraData", { storenum: storenum }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            //Date Format
            var date = new Date(parseInt((item.Time).replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "").split("+")[0]));

            T1_data.push([Date.parse(date.toString()), item.T1]);
            T2_data.push([Date.parse(date.toString()), item.T2]);
        });

        T_options.series.push({ name: 'T1', data: T1_data });
        T_options.series.push({ name: 'T2', data: T2_data }); 

        T_chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(T_options);
    });
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xautjzd/L2TFd/44/

Comment: How your data looks like, your jsfiddle doesn't work. Your data should be sorted by x, ascending.

Comment: x is datime,i have sorted by x,descending,but why it can be correctly display in graph?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve it.the reason is that I didn't sort data by x,ascending.I only sort it by descending and get the latest,but after get the latest data,I didn't sort it by ascending,so it occured the two problems as above descripted. Especially thanks for  Sebastian Bochan,also thanks for the people who help me.Thanks again